# How to create a sequential list of id's using letters instead of numbers?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create an array of sequential ids using letters instead of numbers to use as id's in a table.

This is what I am after:

```
[a, b, c, ---, z, ab, ac, --- az, ba, bb, --- bz, ca, cb, --- cz, da, ----- zzz]
```

Is this possible to create in just Standard SQL? (Preferably not a script or stored procedure) Unfortunately I don't have a clue where to start and can't find any good examples solving something similar to use as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with abc as (
  select chr(i) char from unnest(generate_array(97,122)) i 
  union all select ''
)
select distinct t1.char || t2.char || t3.char as id
from abc t1, abc t2, abc t3
where t1.char || t2.char || t3.char != ''
order by length(id), id
```

with output

[image]
**. . .**    [image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks